# Android Studio 4.0 New->Activity->Blank Activity offers creating a new Wear OS blank activity (on any project)

Tags: android-studio

Just after updating my Android Studio to 4.0 I first noticed it when tried to create a new blank activity on one of the bigger projects that I manage - looked kinda strange.

Then tested on a bunch of other projects with same result. Is it a bug? What's the grand idea?

To be clear none of aforementioned projects target Wear OS, just regular Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

Choose **Empty ACtivity** instead of **Blank Activity** and it will work as expected.